# log4net not logging method name

Tags: c#, asp.net, log4net

I have set up log4net as follows:

In the `AssemblyInfo.cs`:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = @"App_Data\log4net.config", Watch = true)]
```

The conversion pattern is:

```
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
  <conversionPattern value="{%level}%date{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} - %C{1}.%M - %message%newline" />
</layout>
```

And the logger is instantiated as:

```
logger = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

I've also tried:

```
logger = LogManager.GetLogger(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly(), "root");
```

However, the calling method name is not being logged.

What am I missing?

**EDIT**

The logger is being created as follows:

```
logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(LogService));
```

The conversion pattern is as above. The log output is:

> 14/09/2016 13:11:13 INFO  - MyController+d__4.MoveNext - Call NonActionMethod
>
> 14/09/2016 13:11:13 DEBUG - MyController+d__7`1.MoveNext - Begin...

Is it possible to change the format to:

> MyController.

Answer (score 0):

You are only getting a logger with the type name:

```
 LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

You can get the name with: MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name

```
 LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType+"."+MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
```

Comment: It still doesn't write the calling method name.

Comment: I would guess your logging statement is within a delegate which is compiled in to an Anonymous Methods. That is probably the reason you do not see any method name.